# Optimize query - How can I Select highest and lowest row, group by date from datetime column and return array

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo, distinct

I'm new to stack overflow and wanted to ask if you could possibly review my code and give me some tips to improve it and get the needed result.

I started with a table like this:

```
Table `time`:

|id|datetime           |type|
|97|2019-01-16 17:22:41|7   |
|96|2019-01-16 16:25:36|5   |
|94|2019-01-16 08:35:01|2   |
|93|2019-01-16 07:45:28|1   |
```

.. there is other days, with the same scheme, but different types.

To get just the unique dates, I use this query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT date(date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) as uniquedates, active FROM time WHERE active = 1"
```

After this, I use the resulting single days/dates to get the lowest/highest data like this:

```
if($count != 0)
{
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) 
    {
        $dates[] = $row['uniquedates'];
    }
}

foreach($dates as $date)
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT MIN(type) AS lowest, MAX(type) AS highest FROM time WHERE datetime LIKE '%$date%'");
    $result = $statement->execute();
    //error handling
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) 
    {
        echo $date ." -> ". $row['lowest'] ." +> ". $row['highest'] ."<br>";
    }
}
```

So, I get a result like:

```
2018-12-03 -> 1 +> 7
...
2018-12-13 -> 1 +> 7
2018-12-14 -> 5 +> 6
2018-12-17 -> 1 +> 7
...
2018-12-20 -> 1 +> 7
2018-12-24 -> 10 +> 11
2018-12-21 -> 8 +> 9
2019-01-07 -> 1 +> 7
2019-01-08 -> 1 +> 7
2019-01-11 -> 1 +> 7
2018-12-27 -> 10 +> 11
2018-12-28 -> 10 +> 11
2019-01-14 -> 1 +> 7
2019-01-15 -> 1 +> 7
2019-01-16 -> 1 +> 7
...
```

This shows the date and the linked low/high values.

Unfortunately I cannot get the datetime value from there, so I'm stuck here.

**I want to return an array that holds just the datetime  of the lowest and the highest row for each day.**

So from my example of the table, row 93 and 97.

```
|id|datetime           |type|
|97|2019-01-16 17:22:41|7   |
|93|2019-01-16 07:45:28|1   |
```

I am quite sure that this could be done much more easier than my attempt. :)

Thank you for taking your time to read my first post.
Any tip/help/example is highly appreciated!

regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing SQL queries in a loop you're usually doing something that should be part of the SQL.

Try the following:

```
SELECT date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') as d,
  MIN(type) AS lowest,
  MAX(type) AS highest
FROM time
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY d
```

Comment: thank you! That helped a lot to get closer to the best way of doing such queries. I just replaced:
`MIN(type) AS lowest,
  MAX(type) AS highest` 
by
`MIN(datetime) AS lowest,
  MAX(datetime) AS highest` to get the earliest/lastest time of each day!